# Three-way sync: Google, Exchange and various clients (outlook, smartphone)

Tags: sync, exchange, google-calendar, symbian

At work, we use an Exchange server and an Outlook client.
At home, I use Google Calendar and Gmail.
I have a Nokia 5800 (Symbian) smartphone.

Currently, my phone syncs contacts and calendar with Google (via their fake-exchange server and the phone's MfE). I would like to add the Exchange server from work to the mix.

I don't need emails synched on any direction, just contacts and calendar.
How can I do this, assuming I can't install Google Calendar Sync at work because I work with XP 64bit (and installing it in compatibility mode seems to corrupt Outlook)?

Comment: I think that's isn't a good idea to import company related information into Google. Please contact your IT department if this is allowed.
Please note that you need a 32bit-Version of "Google Calendar Sync" for Outlook 2010 32bit even, if you are using Windows 7 64bit. Please also note that Google supports also Outlook 64bit now: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/04/google-calendar-sync-upgrades-outlook.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Funambol ? It provides a [SyncML service free of charge](https://my.funambol.com) and [SyncML clients for all of the devices you have](https://www.forge.funambol.org/download/#start) - works for me.